# Props are undefined on React initialization. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-360

I am creating a VR application with React 360. What I am trying to do is to eventually create an application as shown here [Facebook VR multi surface example](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/example-multisurface.html). I am taking the code for that example and am trying to fit it into my application. However I'm having a problem with the following initialization of my React components.

I have the following react-360 application with the following code `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import connect from './Store';

import {
  asset,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  VrButton,
} from 'react-360';

import Entity from 'Entity';


const ModelView = props => {

  *********** Problem **************
  Why are my props undefined if I am declaring it in the wrapper?
  **********************************

  return (
    <Entity
      style={{transform: [{scaleX: 1.25}, {scaleY: 1.25}]}}
      source={{obj: asset(`${props.planetName}.obj`), mtl: asset(`${props.planetName}.mtl`)}}
    />
  );
};

const ConnectedModelView = connect(ModelView);
export default ConnectedModelView;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ModelView', () => ModelView);
```

From the code above, my props for the `ModelView` should not be undefined. On initialization, it should have the value of `earth`.

The props are supposed to be initialized in `Store.js`. Here is the code below:

```
import React from 'react';

const State = {
  planetName: 'earth'
};

const listeners = new Set();

export default function connect(Component) {
  return class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    state = {
      planetName: State.planetName
    };

    _listener = () => {
      this.setState({
        planetName: State.planetName
      });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      listeners.add(this._listener);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      listeners.delete(this._listener);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component
          {...this.props}
          planetName={this.state.planetName}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Taking a page from the facebook code, what I am doing is initializing model view via `Store.connect` method. This method creates a wrapper around `ModelView` where I am setting the props via `State.planetName`. However, I keep getting undefined and I don't know why. I've hardcoded every part of the code which has `State.planetName` to the value of earth and it still is undefined. The props are not being set to the value I want and I'm not sure why. Can someone out there assist me with why this might be the case? I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're rendering the `ModelView` and not the `ConnectedModelView`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll mark it correct in a bit as it worked but could you answer something for me. In the facebook code found here (https://github.com/facebook/react-360/tree/master/Samples/MultiRoot) in the `TopPosts.js` file, I am more or less following the same pattern but nowhere in that code is `ConnectedTopPosts` being imported. How is it able to work then? I don't how versed you are in `react-360` but if you have any insight, I'd like to know. Thanks.

Comment: @DanRubio ... It's not being imported, it's being created and *exported*. It's imported in `index.js` -- `import TopPosts from './TopPosts'`

Comment: Ok, it looks I'm going to need to read up on `import/export` for ES6, I would have thought that it would be `import ConnectedTopPosts from './TopPosts'` because I had to change `AppRegistry.registerComponent('ModelView', () => ModelView);` to `AppRegistry.registerComponent('ConnectedModelView', () => ConnectedModelView);` Thanks.